# Shift Footer tag to center

Tags: css, center, footer

I am working on a website adapted from http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ 
I want to relocate the footer menu which is float left to center. I have been working on this from 3 days. Kindly help

Comment: Please add code explaining your problem. That will help us to solve your problem.

This question is not explanatory. Please edit it. :-)

Comment: Footer menu means your pagination list ?

Comment: yes my pagination list which is in ul li format... please refer to http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ my site is same except i have added scrollbar content and fullscreen slideshow at the background...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the URL you have given in the question above. The nav has `position: fixed`. Therefore, adding a couple of CSS properties would do the job. You can add the below properties.

```
width: 320px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -160px;
```

The trick is to give `left` as 50% which makes the element to start rendering after (vertical) center of the viewport. Then give `margin-left` as negative to pull it slightly back to left. Now, giving the magnitude of `margin-left` as half of the element's `width` will make sure that the element is pulled back to left in such a way that its vertical center coincides with that of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the navigation menu on footer.. Here is how you can do it..

1. Apply a class to `<nav>` i.e. `<nav class='scrollNav'>`
2. Add CSS stylesheet for class scrollNav

   ```
   .scrollNav {
       margin: 0 auto;
       width: 400px;
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       right: 0;
   }
   ```

Margin will center the navigation. Width you can choose as per your menu bar width. Override position with absolute so that left, right and bottom position will work. And make left, right, bottom to 0. So that it will stick to bottom..

I hope that helps..

Thanks and regards,

Rahul Patil

Comment: Hey Rahul, `margin: auto` does not center the element when the position is set to absolute or fixed. http://jsbin.com/azolot/1